# Tomcat app behind Apache, htaccess auth

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, tomcat

Please help to set up a protection for Tomcat app with .htaccess.

I want to use mod_proxy ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse

My tomcat app: **www.example.com:8085**

What I want is to make it impossible to access the Tomcat app without going through Apache auth first.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the fact tomcat and apache are on same server (else, you need to setup a firewall in front of tomcat which will accept connections to tomcat only from apache server) and your context is named `app`

1. Configure tomcat to listen only on localhost (edit `server.xml` file)

   ```
      <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="127.0.0.1" />
   ```
2. Configure apache for proxy and auth.

   ```
      #httpd.conf
      <Location /app>

        # Authentication
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted access"
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords
        Require valid-user 

        # Proxy to tomcat
        ProxyPass  /app http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse  /app http://127.0.0.1:8080/
      </Location>
   ```